Options for efficiently editing large documents
I have a large document that contains nearly one hundred longtblr or tblr type tables. Even on a powerful computer, this takes several minutes to compile.
I already use \input{}s and split my report into parts so I can comment out all but the part I am editing. However, this pattern is sending me down a rabbit hole of endless nested \input{}s as I try to further split the document by section and more, which is rather untidy.
Although I am using TexStudio on Windows, is there any other editor or process I can adopt to allow me to compile only the section I am currently editing?

\includeonly  ?

@DavidCarlisle That is certainly a more refined approach, but to be honest, it was easier to layer on 100 lines of \input and simply comment all but the few I need, instead of copying and pasting the file names I want into the preamble.

With subfiles you could compile each file individually as well as keep the main file in working order.

it depends what you want, with \include(only)  section counts and cross references to omitted sections still work, if you comment things out then everything re-numbers and cross references to omitted sections fail.

standalone lets you compile the individual files separately or the entire document. The mechanism differs from subfile. The latter always uses the main document's preamble. The former uses the preamble in the individual file and ignores that preamble when including it in the main document. If you do a lot of stuff in the preamble or if you use hooks at the start of the document, standalone is better. If you have a small preamble and don't use hooks at the start of the document, subfiles may be easier.

Alternatively, you should be able to memoize the tables, if you wanted. Then you'd keep the numbering and such without recompiling the tables. You could then turn memoization off for the final run. (Note: this approach is untested, but the manual discusses memoizing a table broken across pages.)

@cfr It seems that subfiles worked well with TexStudio's automatic root document detection behavior. Too bad the \subfilesinclude doesn't preserve section numbers and references. Overall, this worked incredibly well, thank you all!

"endless nested \input{}" If you nest your child documents you can consider import among the other  approaches, but as fan of KISS philosophy (keep it simple, st ...hmm...shrewd!)  my suggestion is maintain only a level of child documents in the working directory. An editor able to show outlines of sections also can help to reduce the need of nest contents.
